# How to get execution time of each test in bazel?

Tags: bazel

When running bazel test the output contains only summary of the all tests, including total run time.

Running bazel with performance profiling does not help, because it does not indicate each test time.

So how to get the info about each test execution time?

**UPD:**

I have a sample repo to reproduce my problem:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/MikhailTymchukFT/bazel-java
$ cd bazel-java
$ bazel test //:AllTests --test_output=all --test_summary=detailed

Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Analyzed 2 targets (20 packages loaded, 486 targets configured).
INFO: Found 2 test targets...
INFO: From Testing //:GreetingTest:
==================== Test output for //:GreetingTest:
JUnit4 Test Runner
..
Time: 0.017

OK (2 tests)


BazelTestRunner exiting with a return value of 0
JVM shutdown hooks (if any) will run now.
The JVM will exit once they complete.

-- JVM shutdown starting at 2020-04-07 09:44:56 --

================================================================================
INFO: From Testing //:MainTest:
==================== Test output for //:MainTest:
JUnit4 Test Runner
.
Time: 0.016

OK (1 test)


BazelTestRunner exiting with a return value of 0
JVM shutdown hooks (if any) will run now.
The JVM will exit once they complete.

-- JVM shutdown starting at 2020-04-07 09:44:57 --

================================================================================
INFO: Elapsed time: 21.009s, Critical Path: 6.68s
INFO: 10 processes: 6 darwin-sandbox, 4 worker.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 18 total actions
Test cases: finished with 3 passing and 0 failing out of 3 test cases

INFO: Build completed successfully, 18 total actions
```

I can see execution time of both tests in GreetingTest

```
==================== Test output for //:GreetingTest:
JUnit4 Test Runner
..
Time: 0.017
OK (2 tests)
```

, but cannot see the execution time of each test in this class/rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`testlogs` folder](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/output_directories.html#layout-diagram) where you can find `.xml` files with the execution times of each testcase.

The `bazel-testlogs` symlink points to the same location.

For my example, these files will be located at `/private/var/tmp/_bazel_<user>/<some md5 hash>/execroot/<project name>/bazel-out/<kernelname>-fastbuild/testlogs/GreetingTest/test.xml`

The content of that file is like this:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name='com.company.core.GreetingTest' timestamp='2020-04-07T09:58:28.409Z' hostname='localhost' tests='2' failures='0' errors='0' time='0.01' package='' id='0'>
    <properties />
    <testcase name='sayHiIsString' classname='com.company.core.GreetingTest' time='0.01' />
    <testcase name='sayHi' classname='com.company.core.GreetingTest' time='0.0' />
    <system-out />
    <system-err /></testsuite></testsuites>
```

Answer (score 3):

With [--test_summary=short](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--test_summary) (the default value), the end of the output looks like this (lines for the other 325 tests truncated):

```
INFO: Elapsed time: 148.326s, Critical Path: 85.71s, Remote (0.00% of the time): [queue: 0.00%, setup: 0.00%, process: 0.00%]
INFO: 680 processes: 666 linux-sandbox, 14 worker.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 724 total actions
//third_party/GSL/tests:no_exception_throw_test                 (cached) PASSED in 0.4s
//third_party/GSL/tests:notnull_test                            (cached) PASSED in 0.5s
//aos/events:shm_event_loop_test                                         PASSED in 12.3s
  Stats over 5 runs: max = 12.3s, min = 2.4s, avg = 6.3s, dev = 3.7s
//y2018/control_loops/superstructure:superstructure_lib_test             PASSED in 2.3s
  Stats over 5 runs: max = 2.3s, min = 1.3s, avg = 1.8s, dev = 0.4s

Executed 38 out of 329 tests: 329 tests pass.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 724 total actions
```

Confusingly, `--test_summary=detailed` doesn't include the times, even though the name sounds like it should have strictly more information.

For sharded tests, that output doesn't quite have every single test execution, but it does give statistics about them as shown above.

If you want to access the durations programmatically, the [build event protocol](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-event-protocol.html) has a [TestResult.test_attempt_duration_millis](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/16a107d/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/buildeventstream/proto/build_event_stream.proto#L408) field.

Alternatively, using [--test_output=all](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--test_output) will print all the output from your actual test binaries, including the ones that pass. Many testing frameworks print a total execution time there.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but I found the info I needed in `testlogs` folder. Please see accepted answer for details.